# I can not put an input in the first place

Tags: php, jquery, selectize.js

I am trying to put as the first option of a select the option of none (to unlink that data).

I am using selectize, using a php page I generate the select with all the input as follows:

```
          <select class='form-control empleadosEquipamientoSelector' id='empleadoPortatil' required>
          <option value='' disabled selected>Seleccione el empleado al que asignar el equipamiento</option>";
          echo "<option value='null'>Any</option>";
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
          $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
          while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'> ".$row['name']." ".$row['surname']." ".$row['secondSurname']."</option>";
          }
          echo "</select>
```

In jquery I have the following order, but only affects the input that is created within the while, if I call it AAAAAAny, the first one should appear according to the ordering criteria but always the last appears, regardless of the value and the text that There is in the input

```
    var $select1 = $('#empleadoPortatil').selectize({
        sortField: {
            field: 'text',
            direction: 'asc'
        }

    });
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in jQuery? Why don’t you sort the data in the SQL statement?

Comment: You take all the reason, I was using it so because I'm using a modal for editing fields, and selectize allows me to easily open the modal the select are with the matching option.
Thank you very much for your help @Manngo

Comment: @Manngo  Can you put your comment as an answer ?, to put it as resolved and to be able to help if someone is trying the same thing

Comment: Will do. I have also suggested a cleaner way of writing your code to make it easier to maintain, if that’s OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem will be solved if you let SQL do all the hard work. That way, your first two items can be whatever you like, and then followed by your generated options.

I would also suggest that you separate the logic from the HTML. In this case, your PHP can do all the hard work, and the HTML simply outputs the result. This will be *much* better for long term maintenance, because you don’t have to switch between to languages all the time, and you can concentrate your (or somebody’s) efforts on one thing at a time.

Here is a suggested re-working of the code:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY …";    //  ORDER BY something
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    $options = array();
    $option='<option value="%s">%s %s %s</option>';
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $options[]=sprintf($option,$row['id'],$row['name'],$row['surname'],$row['secondSurname']);
    }
    $options=implode('',$options);
?>
<select class='form-control empleadosEquipamientoSelector' id='empleadoPortatil' required>
    <option value='' disabled selected>Seleccione el empleado al que asignar el equipamiento</option>
    <option value='null'>Any</option>
    <?php print $options; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Many thanks. I will try to change my code as you indicate, it is true that if I do not mix the languages the code is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "Any" use "--Any--" its a kind of hack not solution else you have to sort before adding.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work, if I use selectize to order I put the last one in all cases.  Thank you very much for your help